# How can an electron have angular momentum when it doesn't orbit the nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, physical-chemistry

Since electrons do not orbit the nucleus like particles, and instead have a probability to "exist" around the nucleus, how can they have an angular momentum as if they move at a certain velocity around the atom?

Also, why does this force the electrons probability density into distinct shapes?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105703/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/179476/50583

Comment: No trajectories is only a part of models and not all interpretations of QM use it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to think of the orbiting electron as crushed onto dust. This dust "cloud" is flying around the nucleus and in total makes up the electron so it carries the electron mass and momentum, although spread out.

If we stay in this crushed-electron analogy then imagine having two electrons. Each of their clouds repel the other because we still imagine this cloud is the full electron with a net charge. Their mutual repulsion distorts their paths now, from being alone and spinning freely and spreading out as an orb to now being two and changing into two distorted orbit shapes, or orbitals. There may even be empty spots were neither cloud dare to move.

---

This analogy is of course not perfect. Why doesn't the cloud particles repel each other within a cloud? Why doesn't it mix with the other electron cloud? We neglect such contradictions for the sake of the analogy in this case. Or you can try to fit a similar analogy onto the probability cloud idea.